# In this sentence, is the correct pronoun me, I, or myself?

Tags: pronouns

I need help with figuring out what pronoun to correctly use at the end of the following sentence:

"As a child, I witnessed my father regularly fight with my mother, and exhibit strong, emotional and physical outburst towards my sister and me/I/myself."

Can anyone explain which one it correct and why?

Comment: The only one that's wrong is the "I" version.

Comment: Using 'me' is not ungrammatical here but would incorporate an unfortunate clash of registers. As would 'Pops was well mean to my sister and myself.'

Comment: Surely 'me' is the only correct option? If the sister was not mentioned it would be 'towards me'.

Answer (score -7):

You would use the pronoun I, as you generally do use the pronoun I, whenever your talking about someone else and yourself.
eg: Maria and I decided to go over to the lake

Comment: Anonymous1010 has it exactly wrong. The use of *I* has nothing to do with its conjunction with additional parties, and as the pronoun here will be the object of the preposition *towards*, the objective as opposed to nominative form would be conventional.

Comment: Because *towards* is, er, ... dative? You are the object at the end of the sentence, so "me" or "myself" are the correct word choices... I'd go with *myself*, myself, but Tom's right.